# Use of HTML5.js to enable in IE8

Tags: html, css

I wanted to understand how useful is the HTML5.js for enabling HTML5 features in IE8
http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Does it enable HTML5 completely OR to some extent in IE8?
Does it have any impact on CSS3 styles like border-radius, gradient, etc ?

Comment: I highly recommend checking out [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) If you want to dabble with html 5  features in older browsers so as to target features and not environments.

Comment: Echoing Andrew's comment: By putting Modernizr on your page, it will forcefully create all the HTML5 semantic tags that IE8 doesn't support so that your page will still render somewhat how you're expecting it to.

Answer (score 1):

All the html5.js script will do is enable the use of proper HTML5 elements such as nav, section etc.

Without the script you can use the elements, but they are ignored, and are not valid as CSS selectors. For example, if you load the script, then css like this `nav { font-weight: bold }` will work, but without it the style will not be applied.

The script does not enable other parts of html5 (video, audio, device for example) or any of the other missing apis like WebSockets, WebWorkers and friends.

It also does not effect any of the css3 styles you mentioned. It will not add border-radius or box-shadow, or any of that functionality, but it will allow already supported css 3 features to be applied to html5 elements. If you want to use those, you would be better looking at other scripts that mimic the behaviour, or something like javascript if you need the animation / transition etc functionality.